# Script error when function/sub parameter is 3 or more in Lotusscipt IBM Notes 9.0

Tags: function, parameter-passing, lotusscript

I have a simple validation code in Lotusscript to check if an entry is already existing in a view. I use a function with 2 parameters passed ByVal, and is working fine.

But when I added a third parameter, it causes script error when called.

Here's a screenshot of the error I get when using 3 parameters in function call:

[image: screenshot of the error]

Here's function parameter setup:

[image: function parameter setup]

I can use a workaround for the third parameter, but it makes no sense adding nested if's or select case inside the function, and will not make the function flexible for other modules.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please edit your post to be more helpful to the people here who can answer it, and to people who will be searching in the future and come here to read and learn. Instead of screen shots, paste your code - both the function definition and the call to the function that is throwing the error. Also, type in the actual error message. (That's what people will search on, most likely, and a picture does not help!)

Comment: Try recompiling the script library containing the function funcValidate_isDuplicateFound. By believing the function still has two parameters the compiled byte code may not have been updated correctly.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the tip... i found out recently, it was save conflict error on the form that caused that.. 
i deleted the form(s) and copied from my backup (which has no codes yet) and it all worked.. but your tip gave me idea.. thanks again